# gcc compiler directive free-form instead of fixed-form

Tags: gcc, fortran, directive, gfortran, freeform

Is there a compiler directive to tell gfortran-gcc compiler that the code is written in free-form? I have code written in a file with '.for' as extension (which is recognized as fixed-form), but the language is f95 free-form.

Adding a flag to the compiler options to force free-form is not possible for my application, hence it needs to be done using directives.

For ifort, the command is:

```
!DEC$ FREEFORM
```

For gfortran is should be something like:

```
!GCC$ DIRECTIVE
```

I have, unfortunately, not been able to find which command exactly.

Comment: Why not simply resuffix the file to `.f90` ?

Comment: If life would only be so easy...:(. In this particular case, I am not allowed to change the resuffix

Comment: You should also consider compiling different sections separately by putting them in different files. If you tell us more about why you can't change the suffix, we may be able to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is none. Use the `-ffree-form` compiler option.